# Questions on ordinals

Tags: set-theory, advice

(Edited)
Background
The following question comes from the order topology chapter from A First Course  in Topology by Conover

**Theorem 4.1** A subset A of R is open in the
Metric topology induced by the absolute value metric iff each point x$\in$ A  there exists real numbers a an  b with a<x<b s.t x$\in$(a,b)$\subset$ A

He then mentions total order relation on a
set X and an order topology on totally ordered set X

(3) There are open subsets of [0,$\Omega$) of
cardinality $\aleph_0$ and subsets of
[0,$\Omega$) of cardinality $\aleph_1$
?

**Question**
What does this question ask of me? I took it to imply to give an example or two as the
book  does

So for the first  one. $\omega$+2=(0,1,2,3...,$\omega$,$\omega$+1),

So |$\omega$+2|=$\aleph_0$

How about $\omega_1$ +1, for the latter?
Then |$\omega_1$+1 |=$\aleph_1$
Though I don’t know how to write the set .

Any help would be appreciated.l hope
this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Can you typeset the question? Images of questions are not searchable and hence are not advised. As is, the question may be closed because of that.

Comment: I removed the image

Comment: It is **not** true that $\vert\omega+2\vert=\aleph_1$; in fact, $\vert\omega+2\vert=\aleph_0$. You can see this by exhibiting an explicit bijection between $\omega+2$ and $\mathbb{N}$ (or $\omega$ if you prefer) - think about [Hilbert's Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel), and consider the "$+2$" to be two new guests.

Comment: So I have to find one for $\aleph_1$ . Can I have an example?

Comment: What is $\Omega$?

Comment: Smallest uncountable ordinal  number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience let $X=[0,\Omega)$. Then $[0,\alpha)$ is a countable open set for each $\alpha\in X\setminus\{0\}$, and $(\alpha,\Omega)$ is an open set of cardinality $\aleph_1$ for each $\alpha\in X$. That these sets are open is immediate from the definition of the order topology. That the sets $[0,\alpha)$ are countable follows at once from the fact that $\Omega$ is the *smallest* uncountable ordinal number: each $\alpha\in X$ is therefore countable, and $[0,\alpha)=\alpha$. Finally,

$$(\alpha,\Omega)=X\setminus[0,\alpha]=X\setminus[0,\alpha+1)\,,$$

$|X|=\aleph_1$, and $|[0,\alpha+1)|=\aleph_0$, so $|\alpha,\Omega)|=\aleph_1$.

Of course there are many other open subsets of $X$ of cardinality $\aleph_0$ and of cardinality $\aleph_1$. For instance, let $A\subseteq X$, and let $U_A=\{\alpha+1:\alpha\in A\}$; then

$$U_A=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}(\alpha,\alpha+2)$$

is open, being a union of open intervals, and $|U_A|=|A|$, so we can start with any subset of $X$ of cardinality $\aleph_0$ or $\aleph_1$ to get an open subset of $X$ of the same cardinality. In fact, if $A$ is any countably infinite subset of $X$, then $U_A$ and $U_{X\setminus A}$ are disjoint open subsets of $X$ such that $|U_A|=\aleph_0$ and $|U_{X\setminus A}|=\aleph_1$